# How is boost::mpl::map (or set) implemented?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

I would like to know how to implement a template metaprogramming structure like [boost::mpl::map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/map.html), that is a structure that *supports constant-time insertion and removal of elements, and testing for membership*.

It is hard to find real implementation in boost headers behind all of workarounds, macros and generated code.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, through clever use of overloading. Let's say you want to to construct a map with just two "elements": `T --> U` and `X --> Y`. If we flatten out all the inheritance hierarchy, we will end up with a type that looks something like this:

```
struct specific_mpl_map {

    U get(T );
    Y get(X );

    template <typename AnythingElse>
    void_ get(AnythingElse );

    pair<T, U> get(int_<0> );
    pair<X, Y> get(int_<1> );

    using size = int_<2>;
};
```

That way, a lookup for some key `K` would just be `decltype(map.get(K{}))`, which is compile-time constant - you don't need to walk through all the pairs to figure out there is a `get(K)`. And you also have a mechanism for iterating in order, via just calling `get(int_<i>{})`. Any insert/delete just creates a new map type with all the new expected `get()` functions.

This isn't exactly what the code looks like, really each `get` is in its own type and the whole thing is inherited linearly up for each `pair` that you add to the map, but this is approximately what the end-goal is.

It helps if you compile with `-E` and then just take a look at what gets dumped out. The key type is something called `m_item`, which defines static functions for each type of lookup. So if we want to do lookup by key, there is:

```
template< typename Key, typename T, typename Base >
struct m_item
    : Base // Base is the rest of the map less this element
{
    // some typedefs

    static aux::type_wrapper<T> value_by_key_(m_item const&, 
                                              aux::type_wrapper<Key>*); 
    using Base::value_by_key_;
};
```

Which `at` uses thusly:

```
template< typename Map, typename Key >
struct m_at
{
    typedef aux::type_wrapper<Key> key_;
    typedef __typeof__( Map::value_by_key_( 
                        aux::ptr_to_ref(static_cast<Map*>(0)), 
                        static_cast<key_*>(0) )

          ) type;
};
```

Where the base empty map also defines:

```
template< typename Dummy = na > struct map0
{
    static aux::type_wrapper<void_> value_by_key_(map0<> const&, 
                                                  void const volatile*);
};
```